# Use of undeclared type 'SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate' error

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, side-menu

I am using left side menu from [this pod](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu). here I have given storyboard side menu button to UISideMenuNavigationController **Present Modually Segue** and side menu is working fine and here I want to use its delegate methods [delegate methods](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu#sidemenunavigationcontrollerdelegate)
but here i am getting below error why??

*I have import it in swift file and just clean the build, restart the mac still same error why?? any idea please help me.*

**I have written below code:**

```
import UIKit
import SwiftKeychainWrapper
import SideMenu

class ProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func sideMenubtn(_ sender: Any) {
    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.9)
  }

}

extension ProfileViewController : SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate {
    func sideMenuWillDisappear(menu: SideMenuNavigationController, animated: Bool) {
       view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

**I got this error:**

> Use of undeclared type `SideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate`
>
> Use of undeclared type `SideMenuNavigationController`

This is small demo project you can find pod installing and error here [github demo project](https://github.com/SwiftSamples/sideMenuDemo/tree/master/SideMenuDemo)

please help me.

Comment: Its UISideMenuNavigationControllerDelegate

Answer (score 0):

As I can see in your Podfile.lock you are using SideMenu 5.0.3. This is not the latest version of this library. Please use SideMenu 6.4.7. Replace `pod 'SideMenu'` with `pod 'SideMenu', '6.4.7'` in your Podfile and run `pod update`. With SideMenu 6.4.7 your demo project builds without any errors.

Comment: yes, errors were gone!! but i want left side menu.. in updated version attributes inspector i am not getting `SideMenuNavigationController` to make it `ON`

Comment: i am getting sidemenu tableview from down, please help

Comment: `Failed to set (leftSide) user defined inspected property on (UINavigationController): [<UINavigationController 0x7fcba001e400> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key leftSide.`

Comment: how can i get left side menu, help please

Comment: @iPhoneDev In the documentation available at https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu I see `let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController); SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController`. Do you have it in your project?

Comment: No, how to add `SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: YourViewController)`

Comment: @iPhoneDev Is it necessary to use storyboards in your project?

Comment: @iPhoneDev I think you should ask another question for this problem, in my answer I already explained how to fix the issue that you described in your question.